# Cannot escape Insert mode on Ubuntu PhpStorm IdeaVim

Tags: phpstorm, ideavim

I've downloaded the evaluation version of PhpStorm 2019.2.1, and added + enabled IdeaVim.

It worked fine for a little while, but now once I enter Insert mode, I can't exit by hitting Escape.
If I uninstall and reinstall IdeaVim, it returns to Normal mode, until I hit `i` (or similar) and then I'm back to the same problem.

No idea what else to try, short of re-installing PhpStorm.

Comment: Can you exit insert mode with `<C-[>`?

Comment: Is that a 'c' or ctrl? Etiher way <c-[> just outputs "ccccccc[[[[" ;-), and <ctrl-[> does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant `ctrl-[` :) Do you have anything special in your `~/.ideavimrc`?

Comment: Must be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1752, it's fixed in master branch

Comment: I don't actually have _any_  ~/.ideavimrc yet. Hadn't got around to adding the few things I normally keep in it.
While that issue has the same appearance, I can't actually switching back to normal mode - even with the line cursor.

Comment: However, this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1685 does look a lot like it.

Comment: [Insert escaping vim joke here]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer, but for now this worked for me:

- Download version 0.51 from here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim/versions
- Uninstall the current version of IdeaVim in PhpStorm
- Install the 0.51 from disk

Hope this helps someone in the interim.